# Hot Swap in my IntelliJ doesn't work. What is wrong?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hotswap

I tried to use the hot swap function in IntelliJ. I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HV50Jzk4MM0).I changed some code in a method. Then, I clicked rebuild, and in the popped up dialog, I clicked "reload", it only shown a dialog above the debug tab, telling me to stop the debug session. It did not change my running program. What's wrong?

This is the screenshot: It told me to stop debug session

[image: screenshot of problem]

I tried to follow the video. I expect my program will change while it's running, but it didn't.

Here's my video showing what did I do: [video](https://youtu.be/AqWLAWZ-nBQ)

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly was changed in the code and what was the expected result. Record a short video, maybe, if you can, or make a few more screenshots.
Looking at your screenshot, it seems like it should have went as the video showed.

Comment: Here's the video: https://youtu.be/AqWLAWZ-nBQ. I just made a new project, which is not the program I'm working on, but It can show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the video you are changing the method that is already being executed (main), if you create another method and call it from main HotSwap will work as you expect it to work.

For more info see [HotSwap Limitations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#reload_classes) section.

DCEVM can help you get around the limitations of the default HotSwap implementation.
You can check this [Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9552-hotswapagent), for instance.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Java IDEs and VMs support a feature called HotSwapping. It allows you to update the version of a class while the virtual machine is running, without needing to redeploy the webapp, restart, or otherwise interrupt your debugging session. (source: [source](https://www.labkey.org/Documentation/wiki-page.view?name=hotSwapping#:%7E:text=Java%20IDEs%20and%20VMs%20support,otherwise%20interrupt%20your%20debugging%20session.))

Basically hot-swap updates your classes by reloading. As output says:

> 8 classes reloaded

Your classes should be updated.

Comment: Thank you, but can you check out the video I have just posted? It just don't work.

Comment: This is not how hot swap works.
"Changes to your class will be reflected AFTER the current stack has exited your method."
You are in an endless loop which means it does NOT exit your stack. 
Please check link: https://www.labkey.org/Documentation/wiki-page.view?name=hotSwapping